# react-final-form custom method typescript

Tags: typescript, react-final-form

I render react final form:

```
<Form render={FormView} onSubmit={onSubmit} initialValues={state} clearForm={clearForm} />
```

and `FormView` located in another file, I use custom method `clearForm` and get it in `FormView`

```
function FormView(props: IProps) {
  const { handleSubmit, clearForm } = props
```

And I get the error:

```
ERROR in src/Filter/index.tsx(34,15):
TS2322: Type '(props: IProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '(props: FormRenderProps<IValues>) => ReactNode'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Property 'clearForm' is missing in type 'FormRenderProps<IValues>' but required in type 'IProps'.
Version: typescript 3.9.5
```

How to expand Form types?